# Searching for text patterns in a log file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression, wildcards

I have a large log file where all the lines contained are of similar format. They can vary a bit, but the format until the first ] bracket is always exactly the same.

```
31.7.112.60 - - [26/Jan/2019:19:32:08 +0330] "GET /product/31284/%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%B4%D9%88%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AC%D9%84%D9%88-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B4-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-BOSCH-WAW28760IR-9Kg HTTP/1.1" 200 41935 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I need to do 2 two things:

A) `GET /product/XXXXX/` 
Search for this pattern on all lines(some lines may not have it), where XXXXX can be a variable number of digits, for example it can be 34213 or 1242 or 1423124, then print the top twenty products in order. This should be in the following format.

```
34286,25
33954,18
33952,17
33956,16
33953,16
```

B)Using the IP address, find and print the number of unique users for each day. This needs to be in the following format.

```
22/Jan/2019,3987
26/Jan/2019,5567
```

Comment: Hello what have you tried so far? What happened (or didn't happen)?

Comment: B) - What sorting is needed here? By date or by value?

Comment: needs sorting by date

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple web-server log. The answer is as simple as the `grep` and `awk`.

Let the name of the log-file is `httpd.log`. You can try this compound command:

```
grep -o 'GET \/product\/[^/]*\/' httpd.log |awk 'BEGIN{FS="\/"}{AA[$3]++}END{for(i in AA){print AA[i]" "i}}'|sort -n -r|awk '{print $2","$1}' |head -n20
```

First part isolate the important text, if present, the second part counts each occurrence of product number and prints the results, , the third sorts the list, and the two last print it in form you specified.

If you want to separate it for each day, you can precede the command with another `grep` to specify a date.

To filter the IP clients you can try yourself by following the example shown above.

Comment: This also outputs things like ```29292?model=58647,10``` , I only need stuff like 33953,16 i.e ONLY search patterns ``GET /product/XXXXX/ ``` where XXXXX is a number of variable length

Comment: As shown in other answer, you can use the regex `GET /product/[0-9]*`.

Comment: I would like to note the important logged status code: ... 200 ... which informs you, that requested page with such product realy exists. You can test this status for warning of some kind of sniffing from robot.

Comment: {AA[$3]++} what is this part doing?

Comment: AA[ ] is numeric array variable, each $3 (third field in the row) occurence does increment its A[$3] member of array. At the end you can print the agragate results saved in AA[ ].

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v pat="GET /product/[0-9]*" -F'[[:blank:]:[]' '
BEGIN           {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}
$0 ~ pat        {match($0, pat)
                 A[substr($0, RSTART+13, RLENGTH-13)]++}
!C[$5,$1]++     {D[$5]++}
END             {for(i in A){if(++j > 20) break; print i "," A[i]}
                 for(i in D) print i "," D[i]}
' file
```

`BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}` - Through the array element, set sorting in descending order of value.
`$0 ~ pat {match($0, pat);A[substr($0, RSTART+13, RLENGTH-13)]++}` - Creating an array with keys corresponding to the product number, the quantity is counted in value.
`!C[$5,$1]++ {D[$5]++}` - Counting unique values. Verification Keys consist of date and IP.
`END {for(i in A){ if(++j > 20) break; print i "," A[i]}` - Printing the first 20 keys and values of the array according to point A).
`for(i in D) print i "," D[i]}` - Printing out the values and the keys sorted by value.

If you need to sort by date for last point, you can redirect the output to the shell command. Change the last line:

```
for(i in D) print i "," D[i] | "sort -rt\"/\" -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1"}
```

Comment: Pretty example how powerful awk is. Well comented. I restricted my answer to be less complex but closer to newbie. But your answer gives lot of impulses to me and to higher level unix users. Thanks